# Progressions - Is it G.P. or H.P.?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across the following example yesterday and could not figure it out. Any help is really appreciated.

Find the sum of the following progression from 1st to 1000th term
3, 5/3, 7/5, 9/7, 11/9, ....

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange !! Here we can help you in any kind of mathematical problems, but you have to show what you have tried. Here, the given series is neither in G.P nor in H.P. They are just in form of $(2k+1)/(2k-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I have only bad news

$$\frac {2k+1}{2k-1}=1+\frac {2}{2k-1}$$

So your sum depends on the harmonic sum of the odds, which depends on a finite sum of the harmonic series itself.   No one has a clean closed form formula for this:

$$\sum_{n=1} ^{N} \frac 1 n $$

Much less this:

$$\sum_{n=1} ^{N} \frac{1}{2 n -1}$$